# Jquery validation library not submitting values

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm trying to make a contact form with jQuery validation library. I want to validate the form and post into a php file & also show response without page loads.

I tried the jQuery with validation library :

Here **contact.js**

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    /* handling form validation */
    $("#contact-form").validate({
        rules: {
            full-name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            subject: "required",

                phone: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            },

            message: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10,
                maxlength: 2000
            },
        },
        messages: {
            full-name:{
              required: "please enter your full name."

             },
            email:{

            required: "please enter your email address",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"

        },
        subject: "Please enter a subject",
        phone: {
            required: "Please enter your phone number",
            digits: "Please enter a valid phone number"

            },
        message: "Please enter your message",

        },
        submitHandler: submitForm
    });
    /* Handling login functionality */
    function submitForm() {
        var data = $("#contact-form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'process_contact.php',
            data : data,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#notification").fadeOut();
                $("#submit-button").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; sending ...');
            },
            success : function(response){
                if(response=="ok"){
                    $("#submit-button").html('&nbsp; Sending ...');
                    //setTimeout(' window.location.href = "dashboard.php"; ',4000);
                } else {
                    $("#notification").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                        $("#notification").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+response+' !</div>');
                        $("#submit-button").html('&nbsp; Send');
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

HTML Code : (contact.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">
<head>
<title>The Nest - Real Estate HTML Template</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/validation.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/contact.js"></script>
<!-- Custom stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="style_sheet" href="css/skins/default.css">
</head>
<body>


  <div class="contact-1 content-area-7">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="main-title">
              <h1>Contact Us</h1>
          </div>
          <div id="notification" class="notification-box"></div>

          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <!-- Contact form start -->
                  <div class="contact-form">
                      <form id="contact-form" method="post" name="contact-form">
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="form-group fullname">
                                      <input type="text" name="full-name" class="input-text" id="full-name" placeholder="Full Name">
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="form-group enter-email">
                                      <input type="email" name="email" class="input-text" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="form-group subject">
                                      <input type="text" name="subject" class="input-text" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="form-group number">
                                      <input type="text" name="phone" class="input-text" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 clearfix">
                                  <div class="form-group message">
                                      <textarea class="input-text" name="message" id="button" placeholder="Write message"></textarea>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="form-group send-btn mb-0">
                                      <button type="submit" id="submit-button" class="button-md button-theme">Send Message</button>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </form>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Contact form end -->
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <!-- Contact details start -->
                  <div class="contact-details">
                      <div class="main-title-2">
                          <h3>Our Address</h3>
                      </div>
                      <div class="media">
                          <div class="media-left">
                              <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div class="media-body">
                              <h4>Office Address</h4>
                              <p>Vierra Property Broker
  Office 714, Le Solarium, Dubai, United Arab Emirates</p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="media">
                          <div class="media-left">
                              <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div class="media-body">
                              <h4>Phone Number</h4>
                              <p>
                                  <a href="tel:0477-0477-8556-552">office: 0477 8556 552</a>
                              </p>
                              <p>
                                  <a href="tel:+55-417-634-7071">Mobile: +55 417 634 7071</a>
                              </p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="media mb-0">
                          <div class="media-left">
                              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div class="media-body">
                              <h4>Email Address</h4>
                              <p>
                                  <a href="mailto:info@themevessel.com">info@themevessel.com</a>
                              </p>
                              <p>
                                  <a href="http://themevessel.com" target="_blank">http://themevessel.com</a>
                              </p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Contact details end -->
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Not showing any validation errors and response. I want to validate the form first and submit into php file and show response.

Comment: Give quotes to this full-name like 'full-name'

Comment: only for full-name right ?, Yes I given and tried but still same issue

Comment: in messages block also you gave?

Comment: yes.. only for that full-name right. I given in both blocks rules and messages

Comment: Once check my correction in answer.

Comment: It worked !, what was the issue ?, can you just explain that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library issue is one concern.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
    /* handling form validation */
    $("#contact-form").validate({
        rules: {
            'full-name': "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            subject: "required",

                phone: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            },

            message: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10,
                maxlength: 2000
            },
        },
        messages: {
            'full-name':{
              required: "please enter your full name."

             },
            email:{

            required: "please enter your email address",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"

        },
        subject: "Please enter a subject",
        phone: {
            required: "Please enter your phone number",
            digits: "Please enter a valid phone number"

            },
        message: "Please enter your message",

        },
        submitHandler: submitForm
    });
    /* Handling login functionality */
    function submitForm() {
        var data = $("#contact-form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'process_contact.php',
            data : data,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#notification").fadeOut();
                $("#submit-button").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; sending ...');
            },
            success : function(response){
                if(response=="ok"){
                    $("#submit-button").html('&nbsp; Sending ...');
                    //setTimeout(' window.location.href = "dashboard.php"; ',4000);
                } else {
                    $("#notification").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                        $("#notification").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+response+' !</div>');
                        $("#submit-button").html('&nbsp; Send');
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">
<head>
<title>The Nest - Real Estate HTML Template</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="style_sheet" href="css/skins/default.css">
</head>
<body>


  <div class="contact-1 content-area-7">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="main-title">
              <h1>Contact Us</h1>
          </div>
          <div id="notification" class="notification-box"></div>

          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <!-- Contact form start -->
                  <div class="contact-form">
                      <form id="contact-form" method="post" name="contact-form">
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="form-group fullname">
                                      <input type="text" name="full-name" class="input-text" id="full-name" placeholder="Full Name">
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="form-group enter-email">
                                      <input type="email" name="email" class="input-text" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="form-group subject">
                                      <input type="text" name="subject" class="input-text" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="form-group number">
                                      <input type="text" name="phone" class="input-text" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 clearfix">
                                  <div class="form-group message">
                                      <textarea class="input-text" name="message" id="button" placeholder="Write message"></textarea>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="form-group send-btn mb-0">
                                      <button type="submit" id="submit-button" class="button-md button-theme">Send Message</button>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </form>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Contact form end -->
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <!-- Contact details start -->
                  <div class="contact-details">
                      <div class="main-title-2">
                          <h3>Our Address</h3>
                      </div>
                      <div class="media">
                          <div class="media-left">
                              <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div class="media-body">
                              <h4>Office Address</h4>
                              <p>Vierra Property Broker
  Office 714, Le Solarium, Dubai, United Arab Emirates</p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="media">
                          <div class="media-left">
                              <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div class="media-body">
                              <h4>Phone Number</h4>
                              <p>
                                  <a href="tel:0477-0477-8556-552">office: 0477 8556 552</a>
                              </p>
                              <p>
                                  <a href="tel:+55-417-634-7071">Mobile: +55 417 634 7071</a>
                              </p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="media mb-0">
                          <div class="media-left">
                              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div class="media-body">
                              <h4>Email Address</h4>
                              <p>
                                  <a href="mailto:info@themevessel.com">info@themevessel.com</a>
                              </p>
                              <p>
                                  <a href="http://themevessel.com" target="_blank">http://themevessel.com</a>
                              </p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Contact details end -->
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I changed your validation library with an online link, what you can do is instead of your validation library replace with this `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>`